# QGIS: Add attribute from polyline layer to point layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute, qchainage

I want to add an attribute from a vector line layer to a vector point layer.

The vectorline is railwaynetwork. It has been divided into segments automatically. To process the data further I had to convert the lines into points. I wanted defined distances in between so I chose to use the plugin QChaninage. Now I got points in my defined distance. But in the attribute table there aren't any of the original attributes that where in the vectorlines table. How can I connect those attributes with my points?

I already tried to use tools from the toolbox (e.g Join attributes by location tool) but until now I could not solve it.

Comment: Have you tried the **Join attributes by location** tool since the points should lie exactly on the lines?

Comment: yes I tried that one but in the resulting table there hasn't been an added attribute to each point

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I don't see any reason why @Joseph's suggestion wouldn't work. Can you update your question with more information about what happened when you tried `join attributes by location`? Without more information there's no way to know what the issue is.

Comment: I edited my question. If its still not enough information please ask me again.

Comment: I believe join attributes by location did not help because the information of the original vectorline is only saved in segment beginnings and endings, but not in between.